# Passing data to DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

How can I pass data from my textboxes (in form1) to my DataGridView (in form2)?

here is the code i used.

```
DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 2
DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "Customer"
DataGridView1.Columns(1).Name = "Information"

Dim FNAME As String = Form1.TBFNAME.Text.ToString


Dim row As String() = New String() {"FULLNAME", FNAME}
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
row = New String() {"EMAIL", Form1.TBEADD.Text}
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
row = New String() {"ADDRESS", Form1.TBADDRESS.Text}
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
row = New String() {"CONTACT NO.", Form1.TBCONTACT.Text}
```

the dgv have two columns. and the passed data will appear to the 2nd column but whenever i already input the data it's still blank in the dgv

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
```

for the "CONTACT NO" row.
Other than that, it seems fine. Are FNAME,TBEADD,TBADDRESS, and TBCONTACT all standard textboxes? Where is this code called from?

Some troubleshooting suggestions:
Try creating a minimal project with 4 textboxes, a DataGridView, and a button. Put your code above into the Click event of the button. Then try it with the DataGridView and button on a second form. Compare that to your existing project.